# Trying to make a welcome message for new members but most things i have tried seem not to work at all

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

This is my current code base for the Discord bot that i have begun to build. So far I can get it to respond to commands via a separate file that either respond with a definition of terminology or calculate different things. I am now attempting to get it to send a welcome message to the welcome channel when new members join and am having no luck at all. I am pretty new to C# and Discord.net in general and much of what I've learned has come from mixing ideas out of different videos on youtube as well as other answers to similar questions here that I can't get working. Any pointers would be most appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace RCMC_Bot
{
    class Program
    {
        readonly DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private CommandService _commands;
        private IServiceProvider _services;

        public async Task RunBotAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _commands = new CommandService();

            _services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            _client.UserJoined += AnnounceUserJoin;

            string token = File.ReadAllText("token.txt");

            _client.Log += Client_Log;

            await RegisterCommandAsync();

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);

            await _client.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);

        }

        private Task Client_Log(LogMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task RegisterCommandAsync()
        {
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);
        }

        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);
            if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

            int argPos = 0;
            if (message.HasStringPrefix("+", ref argPos))
            {
                var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);
                if (!result.IsSuccess) Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
            }
        }
        public async Task AnnounceUserJoin(SocketGuildUser user)
        {
            var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            embed.WithColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
            embed.Title = "Welcome To RCMC";
            sb.AppendLine(user.Mention);
            sb.AppendLine("A community dedicated to helping people learn how to customize their Nitrado DayZ servers for consoles.");
            embed.Description = sb.ToString();
            var channel = _client.GetChannel(768081313420017696) as SocketTextChannel;
            await channel.SendMessageAsync(null, false, embed.Build());
            Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("F") + " " + user.Mention + " user join");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need have have intents enabled on the discord developer portal for the user joined event to trigger.

Comment: ah, didn't even think to check on that! thankyou. hopefully it'll be working now :) shall just wait for someone to join the server :D

Comment: seems enabling intents wasn't enough to get things working. i'm sure i'm missing/overlooking something simple.

Comment: You haven't really said what exactly isn't working. Even my first response was just an assumption. The event won't fire if intents are not enabled, but I don't even know if your event was firing or not. Does it fire not and still not work? Is it still not firing?

Comment: i'm asking how to get a welcome message working for when new members join the server. i now have the intents enabled, but still appears the code i have doesnt work

Comment: I know what outcome you are looking for. However, you aren't stating exactly what is not working. To send a welcome message, you subscribe to the user joined event and send a message when the event fires. That's the general answer to your question (which you already do). So the question is what exactly is not working for you. Is your AnnounceUserJoin method being run, is an exception being thrown, where exactly are things going wrong. You can't just say "it's not working"

Comment: nothing appears to be happening at all when new users join. so i have to assume its the AnnounceUserJoin method not being run.

Comment: No, you don't have to assume... you need to debug and confirm. You should never be making assumptions about your own code.

Comment: not really sure how to debug this issue, nothing is showing in conole for user joins and the message isn't firing into the channel as expected. being as new to C# as i am i don't see how to proceed as i'm not getting any errors or exceptions thrown

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved! Appears my enabling of intents didnt save properly. Now corrected and welcome message is functioning.